# What will the 2050's earth atmosphere will look like?

Tags: atmosphere, near-future, earth, materials, climate-change

I'm currently developing a project where i have to design a pair of shoes that will resist all or most of the weather conditions in 2050. Due to climate change, shoes or materials used will change, i'll look for them, but i have to know what problematics will i be referencing.

Comment: This question seems highly dependent upon what happens in the next 30 years. Is there a nuclear war? Do we aggressively cut back on carbon emissions, and invest in carbon capture? Do we increase greenhouse gas emissions in pursuit of temporary gains. Without knowing all these factors this question is pretty unanswerable.

Comment: Climate change is very location dependent. Some places will get more water, others will get less. We'll lose some coastline as the water rises by about a foot. Overall, you'd get less effect to shoe manufacturing than cultural shifts, style, propaganda, and material scarcity produce.

Answer (score 3):

I teach climate change to college students and have a PhD in Energy/Climate policy.

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is very much "it depends."  The biggest challenge when it comes to climate change is that we don't really know what the world will look like in 2050 with any degree of specificity, we just know that there's a cluster of things that could happen.

To a minor extent, the 2050 picture is still influenced by mitigation efforts (whether or not we curtail further emissions of greenhouse gasses or not).  To a much greater extent the scenario is influenced by adaptation efforts (how well society changes its behaviors in response to changes in climate).

Here's some rough sketch stuff, though - all of this is location-dependent:

1 - Temperatures will be higher, stay higher overnight in particular, and spend more days above critical thresholds.  This means that if high-heat is an issue already, it's now worse.  There are cities ([like Karachi, Pakistan](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-pakistan-heatwave/pakistan-heatwave-kills-65-people-in-karachi-welfare-organization-idUSKCN1IM2AU)) where heat is already reaching lethal intensity, and climate change will further exacerbate this.  For footwear design, light, breathable materials that can facilitate sweating (the main means by which humans self-regulate their temperature) is called for/marketable.

2 - Precipitation is heavier and more intense in some places. For footwear, good wet-surface traction could be useful, but often such conditions simply keep people indoors.

3 - Certain types of agriculture may be threatened, become more marginal, and/or fall out of cultural favor because of transportation logistics involved. Especially natural rubber in places like Europe and North America.  Various synthetic rubbers are an option, but frequently involve fossil-fuel use to produce so culturally-speaking an alternative material could be marketable as eco-friendly.

4 - Coastal communities, especially those dependent upon shallow-water fishing or shellfish populations will likely experience a variety of economic/ecological pressures. Their target species are under chemical stress from the acidification of ocean water (CO2 + water = Carbonic acid) and increasingly severe and more frequent flooding events are incurring economic losses from property damage and health issues.  Materially speaking, anything inexpensive is favored here.

The [IPCC Summary Report](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/wg2/) has a number of useful datasets including model predictions that you can use to explore these and other impacts at specific locations over specific time frames.